ASP.NET: Webpage doesn't update upon refresh after code changes
The project is run without debugging. The web app only updates upon refresh for code changes in Index.cshtml. Changes in controller .cs files are not reflected in the page upon refresh.
Scenario:

Load HelloWorld_ page in browser.
Change the return value.
Refresh.
Page doesn't show updated return value.

    public class HelloWorld_Controller : Controller
    {
        // GET: /HelloWorld_/
        public string Index()
        {
            return "qwerqwer";
        }
    }

I'd like to know if this is expected behavior. If not, may I know what I need to change in my project? Thank you for the help :)

what versions of Visual Studio (or other IDE), ASP.NET and .NET versions are you using?

possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59104019/479251

@Pac0, VS Community 2017, .NET Framework 4.8

making changes to compiled code at runtime is a feature called "Hot Reload" and AFAIK it was introduced in VS2019.  If you make a change to your controller and recompile and are hosting in IIS rather than the default debug hosting then at worst you just need to edit and save the web.config file (I.e. insert or remove an empty line and save) then F5 your page and the app pool will refresh and reload the new assembly. (Current session will be dumped)

Try to check below things. It will help you to solve your problem.

Ensure you’re running the app in Debug mode, as changes in Debug mode typically take effect immediately without needing to restart the app.

Enable Hot Reload in your project.

Clear your browser cache. ( Sometimes, a caching issue might prevent changes from appearing ).

Perform a full rebuild of the solution.


